# Examples of problems easy in synthetic but hard in analytic geometry, and vice versa

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, examples-counterexamples

What are examples of problems easy in synthetic but hard in analytic geometry, and vice versa? I imagine that an analytic proof of the existence of the nine-point circle would be fairly laborous (since I could not find one), while the synthetic proof is simple.

Comment: One of the earliest  computer programs for manipulating and simplifying algebraic expressions and equations was tested by giving it  the problem of proving that a triangle has an incenter, using only co-ordinates. There were many intermediate steps, involving expressions that each  covered half a page

Comment: To prove analytically that the barycenter of triangle $A_1 A_2 A_3$ exists, treating the vertices a  vectors, just  take the expressions for each of the median lines and observe that $(A_1+A_2+A_3)/3$ lies on all three lines. I think this is a little easier, and simpler, than a synthetic proof.

Comment: There is a nice proof of Morley's Theorem in "Introduction To Geometry" by Coxeter... I would not dream of trying to prove it analytically.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Nice examples. Would you mind writing them out as a proper answer? So I could select it.